# Business Central REST API filtering expanded field

Tags: rest, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

so i have this problem for which I cannot seem to find any documentation or solution. (the data in the pictures is fake)

I am using Business Central (Dynamics) API for filtering a customer table.
This customer table has an expandable table called **paymentMethod** which I am filtering for **code eq 'CHEQUE'**
When the code does not equal CHEQUE it will return null:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiGl5.png)

When the code equal CHEQUE it will return the expanded table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N0Nx.png)

What I am trying to do is to return only those customers whose paymentMethod code equals CHEQUE, so my logic was to filter for 'paymentMethod ne null' within the query, but this does not seem to work and returns me all customers, with either paymentMethod set to null or as an expandable field.

Any solution to my problem is well appreciated. As I mentioned, I am struggling to return only those customers whose paymentMethod code equals 'CHEQUE'

Thank you so much

This is my query:

```
customers?$select=*&$expand=paymentMethod($select=id,code;$filter=code eq 'CHEQUE')&$filter=paymentMethod ne null
```